# StaleElementReferenceException Error on Java- selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am getting `StaleElementReferenceException` when I run my code for selecting "Buy NOW" from flipkart.com. This is what I have, but its not working for me.

```
public void SelectItemfromPage(){

    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();

    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wd.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
    WebElement element = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-top-search-box']"));
    element.sendKeys("moto g");
    element.submit();


    element.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='products']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]/img")).click();
    element.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainbody-id']/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/input[9]")).click();
}
```

Comment: Homewrecker has the right answer. Also... doing `element.findElement()` only searches children of `element`, not the entire page... which is probably also not what you intended here.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is all wrong. 
You are saving an WebElement and reusing it, that's not the way to go.
When you save a WebElement in an object, in this case element, the WebElement will become stale whenever the DOM changes.
What you need to do is the following:

```
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();

wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wd.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
WebElement element = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-top-search-box']"));
element.sendKeys("moto g");
element.submit();


wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='products']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]/img")).click();
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainbody-id']/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/input[9]")).click();
```